# Custom class for generating Session Id in glassfish

Tags: java, configuration, glassfish, sessionid

I have build a class that implements com.sun.enterprise.util.uuid.UuidGenerator and I want to replace the default session id generator of GlassFish 2.1.1 with my class.

GlassFish has an option in its GUI which is Configuration->Web Container->Manager Properties and there is a "Session ID Generator Class Name" field in which you declare your custom class for generating session IDs.

The problem is that I don't know in which folder I need to put the class into so that GlassFish finds it.

All I get so far is this from the logs:

```
Log Level SEVERE  
Logger  javax.enterprise.system.container.web  
Name-Value Pairs  _ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;_RequestID=6387aa6c-c226-4f09-bd87-66e10ec24744;  
Record Number 411  

Message ID  Unable to load session uuid generator MyUuidGenerator java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

**Complete Message**

```
MyUuidGenerator at com.sun.appserv.server.util.ASURLClassLoader.loadClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:129) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169) at com.sun.enterprise.web.MemoryStrategyBuilder.initializePersistenceStrategy(MemoryStrategyBuilder.java:99) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.configureSessionManager(WebContainer.java:1945) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.configureSessionSettings(WebContainer.java:1878) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1528) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadStandaloneWebModule(WebContainer.java:1052) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadDefaultWebModules(WebContainer.java:1038) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.start(WebContainer.java:868) at com.sun.enterprise.web.PEWebContainer.startInstance(PEWebContainer.java:790) at com.sun.enterprise.web.PEWebContainerLifecycle.onStartup(PEWebContainerLifecycle.java:84) at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationServer.onStartup(ApplicationServer.java:442) at com.sun.enterprise.server.ondemand.OnDemandServer.onStartup(OnDemandServer.java:120) at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.run(PEMain.java:411) at com.sun.enterprise.server.PEMain.main(PEMain.java:338) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at com.sun.enterprise.server.PELaunch.main(PELaunch.java:412)
```

Answer (score 0):

The class has to be on the GlassFish classpath, so you can put in in

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME/lib/
```

or

```
$GLASSFISH_HOME/domains/$YOUR_DOMAIN/lib/classes
```

Comment: I have tried both and nothing works. I have put it with a package, without a package, with .class, without .class.
Nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Need to create a `.jar` with your session id generating class and place that `.jar` in the classpath and then state the name of the class without prefix in the `Configuration > Web Container > Manager Properties > Session ID Generator Class Name`.